# SwiftUI: How to pass a dynamically generated parameter to child View via NavigationLink?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I want to put three links in a NavigationView.

- First link: Displays a RoomView with a specific room ID, "room.A"
- Second link: Displays a RoomView with a specific room ID, "room.B"
- Third link: Displays a RoomView with a randomly generated room ID when the user clicks.

The following code does not work, because SwiftUI calls UUID().uuidString when it builds the NavigationView, and reuse it.

I want to generate a new random room ID when the user clicks the link, but I am not able to figure out how to do it. I am looking for a simple and natural way to achieve this.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: RoomView(roomId: "room.A")) {
                    Text("Enter Room A")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: RoomView(roomId: "room.B")) {
                    Text("Enter Room B")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: RoomView(roomId: UUID().uuidString)) {
                    Text("Create a new Room and enter")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RoomView: View {
    let roomId: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("Room View \(roomId)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a RoomView in the code.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the navigation link is performed eagerly. I made a view to run the creation on tap.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LazyView<Content>: View where Content: View {

    private let viewBuild: () -> Content

    fileprivate init(_ viewBuild: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.viewBuild = viewBuild
    }

    init(_ viewBuild: @escaping @autoclosure () -> Content) {
        self.init(viewBuild)
    }

    var body: some View {
        viewBuild()
    }

}

extension NavigationLink {

    init<V>(lazyDestination: @escaping @autoclosure () -> V, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label) where Destination == LazyView<V> {
        self.init(destination: LazyView(lazyDestination), label: label)
    }

    init<V>(lazyDestination: @escaping @autoclosure () -> V, isActive: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)
    where Destination == LazyView<V> {
        self.init(destination: LazyView(lazyDestination), isActive: isActive, label: label)
    }

    init<V, T>(lazyDestination: @escaping @autoclosure () -> V, tag: T, selection: Binding<T?>, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)
    where T : Hashable, Destination == LazyView<V> {
        self.init(destination: LazyView(lazyDestination), tag: tag, selection: selection, label: label)
    }

}

extension NavigationLink where Label == Text {

    init<V>(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, lazyDestination: @escaping @autoclosure () -> V) where Destination == LazyView<V> {
        self.init(titleKey, destination: LazyView(lazyDestination))
    }

    init<V, S>(_ title: S, lazyDestination: @escaping @autoclosure () -> V) where S : StringProtocol, Destination == LazyView<V> {
        self.init(title, destination: LazyView(lazyDestination))
    }

    init<V>(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, lazyDestination: @escaping @autoclosure () -> V, isActive: Binding<Bool>)
    where Destination == LazyView<V> {
        self.init(titleKey, destination: LazyView(lazyDestination), isActive: isActive)
    }

    init<V, S>(_ title: S, lazyDestination: @escaping @autoclosure () -> V, isActive: Binding<Bool>)
    where S : StringProtocol, Destination == LazyView<V>  {
        self.init(title, destination: LazyView(lazyDestination), isActive: isActive)
    }

    init<V, T>(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, lazyDestination: @escaping @autoclosure () -> V, tag: T, selection: Binding<T?>)
    where T : Hashable, Destination == LazyView<V> {
        self.init(titleKey, destination: LazyView(lazyDestination), tag: tag, selection: selection)
    }

    init<V, S, T>(_ title: S, lazyDestination: @escaping @autoclosure () -> V, tag: T, selection: Binding<T?>)
    where S : StringProtocol, T : Hashable, Destination == LazyView<V> {
        self.init(title, destination: LazyView(lazyDestination), tag: tag, selection: selection)
    }
}
```

Then in your code, replace with

```swift
NavigationLink(lazyDestination: RoomView(roomId: UUID().uuidString)) {
                    Text("Create a new Room and enter")
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution, but this exposes the weirdness of SwiftUI.
This code and the code above are logically identical, but behave differently because of the optimization of SwiftUI.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: RoomView(roomId: "room.A")) {
                    Text("Enter Room A")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: RoomView(roomId: "room.B")) {
                    Text("Enter Room B")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: NewRoomView()) {
                    Text("Create a new Room and enter")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct NewRoomView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RoomView(roomId: UUID().uuidString)
    }
}
```